# SYNTAX error with Update statement VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a SYNTAX error in the UPDATE statement. Plz Help.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_User SET ([Score], [Level])VALUES(@User_Score, @User_Level) WHERE User=@User"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Score", lblScore.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Level", lblLevel.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", txtUser.Text)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it compile? Have you checked the value of `CommandText` at runtime (and ran it in SQL Management?).  This will narrow down your problem.

Comment: Yes i have fixed the problem. Thanks for suggestion for SQL Management

Comment: No problem, you'll get better with experience :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) syntax style, not the [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177523.aspx) syntax:

```
UPDATE tbl_User SET [Score] = @User_Score, [Level]= @User_Level WHERE User=@User
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I also just figured out how to do it another correct way.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_User " & vbCrLf & "SET User_Score=@User_Score," & vbCrLf & "User_Level=@User_Level" & vbCrLf & "WHERE User=@User"`